# Using StandardSQL via ODBC

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm connecting to BigQuery using Simba's ODBC driver and I'm getting this error:

```
SQLState: HY000, Native Error: 100
Message: [Simba][BigQuery] (100) Error interacting with REST API: 2.1192 - 2.1215: Unrecognized function regexp_contains
```

I suspect this is because BigQuery doesn't know I'm trying to talk StandardSQL rather than LegacySQL. How do I use StandardSQL via ODBC?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the "Language Dialect" and set it to "Standard SQL" in the ODBC driver advanced options from the ODBC admin page. If you are configuring the driver via the INI file, set `SQLDialect` to `1`.

Another way to use StandardSQL is to prefix your queries with `#standardSQL`. Example:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  weight_pounds, state, year, gestation_weeks
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.samples.natality`
ORDER BY weight_pounds DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

(from the docs on [enabling standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql#sql-prefix))

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your help. I tried setting SQLDialect to 1 in my `odbcinst.ini` file, but to no avail. `REGEX_CONTAINS` still fails, while `REGEX_MATCH` works which indicates that legacy SQL is still being used. I'm using the ODBC driver downloaded from [Google's website] (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/partners/simba-drivers/). Perhaps it's an older version that doesn't support this setting?

Comment: The [Simba documentation](http://www.simba.com/products/BigQuery/doc/ODBC_InstallGuide/mac/content/odbc/bq/options/ui/sqldialect.htm) does mention this setting but it also says 1 is default, which is  clearly not in my case, so something is off here.

Comment: As to using the `#standardSQL` query prefix, it's not very easy for me to test as I'm using generated SQL. I could rewrite the code, however, I'm a bit discourage by the FAQ on the [BigQuery ODBC drivers page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/partners/simba-drivers/) which states that query prefixes are not supported by ODBC drivers...

Comment: I actually tried prepending '#standardsql' to my queries. However, this results in the following error: `(20) Query execution failed: Query text specifies use_legacy_sql:false, while API options specify:true`. So the only option is using the ODBC config option correctly.

Comment: Are you able to contact support about this? Something seems unexpected about your installation.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out now. The two options that worked for me are:

1. Adding `SQLDialect=1` to the **data source** configuration in the `odbc.ini` file
2. Adding `SQLDialect=1` to the connection string.

Options that did **not** work were:

1. Adding `SQLDialect=1` to the driver configuration in the `odbcinst.ini` file.
2. Prepending queries with `#standardsql`